# Attempting to display image on front end (using react native, nodejs and amazon s3)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-native, amazon-s3

I am attempting to add a functionality where users can select a profile pic from their mobile gallery and set it. For this, i am using react native and nodejs. I successfully upload a file to s3 using nodejs, get a URL and store that URL in the database as the users profile pic. I now need to do the front end, and i am really struggling with this. How would load the URL in react native so the profile pic is visible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy:

```
import {Image} from 'react-native';
<Image
   style={{width: 300, height: 300}}
   source={{uri: _urlOfImage}} />
```

Comment: Hey friend. Thank you so much but one thing. I have implemented upload in node(my backend) and get the url from there, so.how would i know what the upload url is. If a user selects an image how do i get the url from the backend?

Comment: How would i get the url of an image the user uploaded, when i have the url in the backend ?

Answer (score 0):

data.location is the path of image stored in aws

```
s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
if (err) {
console.log("Error", err);
}
if (data) {`enter code here`
res.json({ "imagAwsPath": data.Location })
}
```